# How can I show $R^n$ is dense in $S^n$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compact-manifolds

How can I show $R^n$ is dense in $S^n$?
I wanted to show $S^n$ is compactification of $R^n$. for this I need $R^n$ is not compact, for this there is no problem, and $S^n$ is compact, I did it with stereography, because it's covered by finite open set, Now I want to show $R^n$ is dense in $S^n$, for this maybe easier work with $(0,1)$ instead of $R$ because they are isomorphic, Is that correct? could you help me for further?

Comment: Literally, "You can't", because $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ is not a subset of $S^{n}$. Perhaps you have a particular embedding $i:\mathbf{R}^{n} \to S^{n}$ in mind? (Note, separately, that a topological space with a finite covering is not generally compact: _Every_ space is covered by one open set, namely itself.)

Comment: Then how can I proof this compactification?!

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a topological space and $a\in X$ is not an isolated point, then $X\setminus\{a\}$ is dense in $X$. Indeed, any open subset $U$ of $X$ that fails to intersect $X\setminus\{a\}$ must ba a subset of $\{a\}$. As $\{a\}$ is not open, such $U$ must be empty. In other words, every non-empty open $U$ intersects $X\setminus\{a\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\Bbb R^n$ is realized as the obvious homeomorphic copy $X \subset S^n$ of it inside the one-point compactification $S^n$, then just note that any neighborhood of the point $\infty$ at infinity, in the one point compactification $S^n$, intersects $X$.

So $\infty$ is a limit point of $X\subset S^n$, and tautologically the only limit point as $S^n - \Bbb R^n$ contains nothing except $\infty$. Thus taking closure adds the point at infinity to $X$, hence $\text{cl}(X) = S^n$. That proves that $X$ is dense in $S^n$.